# new and delete in C program

Tags: c

I have the following algorithm to implement new in C

```
void *newinc(unsigned int s)
        {
                // allocate and align storage of size s

                // handle failure via exception

                // return pointer to storage
        }
```

I have the following implementation:

```
 void *newinc(unsigned int s)
{
   int *p = (int *)malloc(s * sizeof(int));
    return p;
}
```

I believe the first and the last step mentioned in the algorithm have been achieved by the program,how do I implement the second line in the algorithm: 
// handle failure via exception
I believe C program does not have try/catch blocks to catch exceptions.

Comment: C also doesn't have operator defining/overloading...

Comment: You seem to be confused about **which language you want to speak**. That's an important decision to make *before* you start writing source code.

Comment: C in title, C++ in tag - something's wrong.

Comment: That edit only makes it *worse*. What part of "*C does not have operator new*" don't you understand? You are using **C++**.

Comment: @Nicol does it look fine now...sorry for the confusion

Comment: @user1035927: No. C++ and C are not the same language. You are using C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are wanting an implementation in C, not C++? The following is all under the assumption that you really want C.

To start with, C does not know the keyword `operator`, and you cannot give a function a name with two words. Therefore you will need to give your function a different name, like `operator_new`. Given that your function obviously only works for ints (there's no way in your interface to give information about the type, and your example implementation allocates space for `s` `int`s), I'd suggest `new_ints` instead (since C doesn't have constructors, the distinction between `new` and `operator new` is moot). Alternatively you might want to pass on arguments telling about the size of the type you want to allocate. You can even pass on a pointer to a function you want to be called as "constructor" for your objects (using a `void*` interface).

Also C has no exceptions. You may somewhat emulate them with `setjmp`/`longjmp`, however since C doesn't know destructors it will not do cleanup for you. Code aware of your hand-made exception handling may however implement cleanup explicitly through a chain of `setjmp` buffers. However, those setjmp buffers need to be passed on to your function, either using extra arguments, or using a global variable. All in all, the better option in C is to just return `NULL`, as `malloc` does. However, if you insist on the exception part, this is how you might do it (untested):

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* operator_new(size_t s,     /* how many bytes to allocate */
                   jmp_buf env)  /* the "exception" information */
{
  void* block = malloc(s);
  if (!block)
    longjmp(env, 1); /* 1 is an "error code" */
  return block;
}
```

The function would then be called as follows:

```
int main()
{
  volatile jmp_buf env; /* I'm actually not sure if this has to be volatile,
                           but longjmp may mess up some non-volatile variables */
  if (!setjmp(env)) /* try */
  {
    int* p = operator_new(10*sizeof int, env);
    /* use p */
    free(p)
  }
  else /* catch(...) */
  {
    /* handle the error */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical naive `new`/`delete` implementations in C++:

```
void * operator new(std::size_t n) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    void * const p = std::malloc(n);

    if (!p) throw std::bad_alloc();

    return p;
}

void operator delete(void * p) throw()
{
    std::free(p);
}
```

In C++11, the exception specifications change to “none” for `operator new()` and to `noexcept` for `operator delete()`.

The adult version of the `new` operator would first loop `set_new_handler()` before throwing.

Alignment guarantees follow those of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <exception>

void *operator new(unsigned int s)
{
    void *block = malloc(s);
    if(block == NULL)
       throw std::exception("Not enough memory.");
    memset(block, 0, s);
    return block;
}
```

Comment: No need for memset and throwing a `const char[N]`? Owch.

Comment: If you want to have your newly allocated block zero-inizialized, it's better to use `calloc` instead of `malloc` and `memset`. The reason is that if new memory has to be obtained directly from the OS (instead of using currently unused memory already owned by the process), it is set to zero by the OS anyway (for security reasons, because otherwise if could contain data from another application), which makes the explicit clearing redundant. I'd expect a quality implementation of `calloc` to only set the memory to zero itself if not already done by the OS.